# How can I Use Add-Type to add C# code with System.Windows.Forms namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I use `Add-Type` to add C# code with `System.Windows.Forms` namespace?
I tried this command:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testnamespace
{
    public static class testclass
    {
        public static string messagebox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test")
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
"@
```

but I'm getting some error like:

> The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I just want to use **ONLY** C# code in PowerShell. Please **don't** give me alternative.

Comment: Use menu Project : Add New Item : Windows Form.  It will automatically set up everything in a new class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a reference to the containing assembly (the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` file), using the `ReferencedAssemblies` parameter:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static string MessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms
```